# Outputting subcategory title AND items on Category page

Tags: categories

When a user clicks on a category, if there is a subcategory, I want it to appear in an h2 and then the items below it.

For example:

- Click on shirts
- See Hanes in title, then items HA101, HA102, HA103
- Below it, see Gildan in title, then items GI101, GI102, GI103

I think I need to edit a PHP template file but not sure which one -- could use a little assistance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png

Here you can view template file name that's best fits for you.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children

Use these function to get current term ( category ) childs. Note that in `taxonomy.php` template you can use `$wp_query->get_queried_object_id();` to get current `term_id` you'r viewing

Use `new WP_Query` to echo posts inside the child terms loop to get posts from child term `new WP_Query( array( '{taxonomy}' => {child_term_id} ) );`

Here's an example:
taxonomy.php ( or better category.php if it's category taxonomy your using )[missing get_header() and get_footer()]

```
global $wp_query;
$cat_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();
$cat_childs = get_term_children( $cat_id, 'category' );
if( $cat_childs ) {
  foreach ( $cat_childs as $cat_child ) {
    $child = get_term_by( 'id', $cat_child, 'category' );
    $child_posts = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'terms'    => $child->term_id,
            'include_children' => false
        )
      )
    ) );
    if( $child_posts->have_posts() ) {
      echo '<h1>' . $child->name . '</h1>';
      while( $child_posts->have_posts() ) : $child_posts->the_post();
        the_title();
        echo "\r\n";
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();
    } 
  }
} else {
 // there's no category childs
}
```

Comment: I'm not a programmer, so please be patient

this will get the name of the category if placed in taxonomy.php?

$wp_query->get_queried_object_id(category); 

and placing this inside the loop where each category is pulled will display before each set of items?

WP_Query( array( '{taxonomy}' => {category} ) );

Is that right?

Comment: not tested, but should work. See example above @John